# Can aura application event be fired multiple times?

Tags: lightning-apps, aura

I have registered an application event 'ShowModalEvent' in component-1 (Table) and handler in component-2. Component-2 (Modal Dialog) is part of component-1.
I have added **onclick** function call (to show modal) to one of the table column data.

**Component-1 - Helper**

```
generateTableWithLink : function(component, callback) {
..
..
retRecords.forEach(function(row) {
  fields.forEach(function(field){ 
    if(field.name == 'Id') {
      var showModalEvent = $A.get("e.c:ShowModalEvent");
      tableData.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
      tableData.onclick = function() {
         this.showPopup(component, row, showModalEvent);
      }
      tableData.children[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(row[field.name]));
    }
  }
}
..
..
},

showPopup : function(component, row, showModalEvent) {
   showModalEvent.setParams({
            "recordId" : s["Id"],
            "sObjectName" : objectName,
            "modalHeaderTitle" : title
        });
   showModalEvent.fire();
}
```

Application Event 'ShowModalEvent' is supposed to be fired every time the link (column data) is clicked.
But here, Event is working only for the first time and throwing below error for the second try.

**ERROR** : Assertion Failed!: Event.setParams(): cannot modify all params in an event that has already been fired. : false

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a new (additional) **Component event** to invoke controller method of the same component. 
This time, showPopup() in helper fires *Component Event* instead of *Application Event*. 
Added register & handler for *Component Event* in the same component-1 where handler calls a new action method to fire an **Application event**. 
Thus same **Application Event** can be fired multiple times.

**Flow**
Fire_ComponentEvent from showPopup() (Helper method in Cmp-1) --> Handler (in Cmp-1) --> ActionMethodToFireApplicationEvent(in Cmp-1 controller) --> Fire_ApplicationEvent --> Handler (in Cmp-2) --> Final Action method(Cmp-2)

Technically, This solution (fire an application event multiple times) works for the situation but there can be a better and easy approach to invoke child component's controller method() multiple times.

Comment: Tried this approach based on the below page
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XfdAQAS

Answer (score 0):

You just should not pass the event parameter.

Just change your code to this:

```
if(field.name == 'Id') {

  tableData.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
  tableData.onclick = function() {
     this.showPopup(component, row );
  }
tableData.children[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(row[field.name]));
}
```

and this:

```
showPopup : function(component, row ) {
var showModalEvent = component.getEvent("ShowModalEvent");
   showModalEvent.setParams({
            "recordId" : s["Id"],
            "sObjectName" : objectName,
            "modalHeaderTitle" : title
        });
   showModalEvent.fire();
}
```

Comment: For some reason '$A.get("e.c:ShowModalEvent");' could not find component inside showPopup, Hence showModalEvent remains undefined.
     
      -----------
    
I used a new (additional) 'Component event'.  
This time, showPopup method fires 'component Event' instead. 
Added register & handler for Component Event in the same component-1 where handler calls a new action method to fire 'Application event'. 
This is working for firing same 'application type event' multiple times , but I still have to test few scenarios. Please let me know if this approach is Ok to follow. Thanks.

Comment: showPopup --> Fire_ComponentEvent -> Handler -> MethodToFireAppEvent --> Fire_ApplicationEvent

Comment: Sorry, you need to use component.getEvent("ShowModalEvent");

Comment: Sure will try with component.getEvent in some time and update. Thanks @Patlatus

Comment: I am using **Application Event** as the component which has handler is actually a child in this case. 
    .
    To my understanding, **ComponentEvent** would bubble the event up to the parent component and more components listening for this event, only the parent on the hierarchy would handle that and not the child component. Kindly Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Neither Component.getEvent("ShowModalEvent") nor $A.get("e.c:ShowModalEvent") could able to return event inside this showPopup method.  In-fact *this.showPopup()* method call is inside callback function. Does this matter? Please help.