# Can I save and fire lightning event later?

Tags: lightning, event, lightning-events

I am trying to fire the same lightning event from one component more than once. Is it possible to save the event in a variable and use it to fire?

I saw [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159989/can-aura-application-event-be-fired-multiple-times) question. It did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Attempting to fire an event more than once results in the following error:

> ```
> Assertion Failed!: Event.fire(): Unable to fire event. Event has already been fired. : false
> ```

You can get an event and hold on to it indefinitely, but you cannot use it again afterwards. You must get a fresh copy each time.

Comment: Only component events can be fired multiple times.